# When start writing in the input just appear "loading" instead of the places drowpdown - react-places-autocomplete

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-places-autocomplete and when I start typing in the input to search for a place the only thing that appears is "loading..." instead of the dropdown with the suggestions.
This is my code:

```
componentDidMount(){

    window.initMap = this.initMap
    const gmapScriptEl = document.createElement(`script`)
    gmapScriptEl.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap`
    document.querySelector(`body`).insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, gmapScriptEl)
  }

  initMap = () => {
    this.setState({
      googleMapsLoading: true,
    })
  }

  handleChange = address => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  handleSelect = address => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {

            this.state.googleMapsLoading ?
            <PlacesAutocomplete
        value={this.state.address}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
          <div>
            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                className: 'location-search-input',
              })}
            />
            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
              {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
              {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                const className = suggestion.active
                  ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                  : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                  ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                  : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  <div
                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                      className,
                      style,
                    })}
                  >
                    <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </PlacesAutocomplete> : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I had to add the initMap function because I had the loader error. I dont know why the suggestions array is empty.
Thanks

Comment: Hi..Can you please post geocodeByAddress function

Comment: Hi, geocodeByAdress its being imported `import PlacesAutocomplete, {
  geocodeByAddress,
  getLatLng,
} from 'react-places-autocomplete';`

Comment: Seems to be issue with their server https://hibiken.github.io/react-places-autocomplete/ try entering the text I am getting request denied error..